# c# iterate over nested key value pair

Tags: c#, nested, key-value

I have a `KeyValuePair<string,object>` and the object is also a KeyValuePair.  I have been trying to cast the object to a new KeyValuePair so that I can iterate through the values, but so far all attempts have failed.  Does anyone have any ideas.  Thanks.

```
var installers = manifestDict.Where(kvp => kvp.Key.Equals("Installers"));
foreach(var i in installers)
{
     var newKvp = i.Value;
     //how to cast this object to a new kvp?
}
```

[image]

Comment: Doesn't work because it's not IEnumerable and all my attempts to cast it to one have failed.

Comment: I suspect you are not casting to the right type. Try a `Console.WriteLine(i.Value.GetType());` to debug this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It ended up that I needed to cast to a list first.

```
 foreach(var i in installers)
 {
      var newKvp = i.Value as List<object>;
      foreach(var z in newKvp)
      {
           var result = (Dictionary<object,object>) z;
      }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me it is another dictionary, no?

So you should cast it to *Dictionary<string, object>*

```
var installers = manifestDict.Where(kvp => kvp.Key.Equals("Installers"));
foreach(var i in installers)
{
     var newKvp = (Dictionary<string, object>)i.Value;
     //how to cast this object to a new kvp?
}
```

btw u can also write it like this if you certain you have that key:

```
var installers = (Dictionary<string, object>)manifestDict["Installers"];
foreach(var installer in installers)
{
     //This will itenrate all your key value pairs inside installers
     Console.WriteLine(installer.Value);
}
```

Comment: Close.  That's what I was trying, but it was still throwing an exception.